# Gulp Watching Creates Infinite Loop Without Changing Files

Tags: node.js, gulp, watch

Similar to other questions, in this very watered-down snippet, running the *default* gulp task (via `npm start` which runs `gulp`); this snippet creates an infinite loop running the scripts task over and over.  Here is the *gulpfile.js* (literally the whole thing at the moment):

```
'use strict';

const gulp = require('gulp');

// COPY SCRIPTS TO BUILD FOLDER
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('./scripts/**/*.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/scripts'))
});

// WATCH FILES
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});

// DEFAULT
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

The extra odd thing is that whether the *build* folder is built anew or not, the scripts task will be executed immediately after calling `npm start`!  And the loop begins.

In case you're curious, here is the pasted (and only) scripts object in my *package.json*:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "gulp"
  },
```

The only other thing in my directory is a *scripts* folder with an *app.js* and an *home.js* file in it.  Obviously once this task is run, the *build* folder is created (if it wasn't already there yet) and the two aforementioned files are copied into it.

You can see I'm only looking for scripts in the root directory's first level folder called scripts, so I shouldn't have an infinite loop by referencing changes on the same set of scripts.  Also, even if I'm explicit, and point to exactly one particular file with a relative path such as `./scripts/home.js` this still happens.

I'm anticipating being embarrassed, but I'm utterly confused.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I've picked up on which could be causing some errors.

EDIT -
Try the watch plugin `npm install --save-dev gulp-watch`

```
// Try and declare your plugins like this for now.
var gulp  = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch');

// Provide a callback, cb
gulp.task('scripts', function(cb) {
  // Dont use ./ on your src as watch can have a problem with this
  return gulp.src('scripts/**/*.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/scripts'), cb); // call cb and dont forget ;
});

// remove ./ on watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

So that is pretty weird behaviour but this should do the trick.
The only time I use `./` within gulp is on my dest.

Also just remember that gulpfile is just a JS so remember your semicolon, etc.

Comment: The [`gulp-watch` plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch) and the built-in [`gulp.watch()`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob--opts-tasks-or-gulpwatchglob--opts-cb) are entirely different things. Since he's using the built-in, `require('gulp-watch')` is unnecessary.

Comment: I agree with @SvenSchoenung and didn't need to add another dependency and call back.  The relative paths have always worked for me in other Node stacks.  It appears to have just been some environmental issues.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot guarantee the resolution here, but I had a two variables that changed when this was resolved:

- I upgraded my Parallels VM application (on an Apple PowerBook) from
  version 10 -> 11.
- I reinstalled Windows 10 using another license for a current version
  (the previous one was a licensed dev or early release version).

My code, Node version, devDependencies and versions were identical.